# Loading pickle ML model in Django causes website to freeze

Tags: python, django, apache, pickle

I have a Django application using Apache that runs a website and on the back end, I need to run a machine learning model.

I have trained and saved the model using pickle and am storing it in a "ml_models" directory off of the main directory.

In my directory, I have urls.py pointing to my function that I am calling to run the model:

`path('classify', views.classify),`

in the views.py, I have the function:

```
def classify(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        str_data = request.GET.get("data")
        dataSplit = str_data.split(",")
        sendData = dataSplit[4] + "," + dataSplit[5] + "," + dataSplit[6]
        data = [[float(x) for x in sendData.split(",")]]
        model_path = settings.ML_ROOT +  '/my_model.sav'
        with open(model_path, 'rb') as f:
            model = pickle.load(f)
            prediction = float(model.predict(data))
            f.close()

        r = {"response": str(int(prediction))}
        return JsonResponse(r)`
```

The data I'm sending is in the form:

```
<mysite>/api/classify?data=1,1.2,42.2,12.3,57.84,0.2,29.67,0.95,3

data[0] = device ID, int
data[1] = sensor measurement, float
data[2] = sensor measurement, float
data[3] = sensor measurement, float
data[4] = sensor measurement, float
data[5] = sensor measurement, float
data[6] = sensor measurement, float
data[7] = calculated value, float
data[8] = Project ID, int
```

The data comes from a mobile app (Android and iPhone) that is connected via bluetooth to a sensor suite. The values are numerical data from the hardware I'm using to record constantly changing sensor measurements and get a prediction from some of the values.

What happens is:
When I first open the website, it will load fine.
If I make a call to the prediction, it will work once.
Any subsequent call, the server acts like it's frozen and I eventually get a "Gateway Timeout".

Ideally, I want to make a prediction once every second.
I have tried slowing it down to do once every 60 seconds and get the same result.

I have tested it with both POST and GET requests and it behaves the same with each.

I discovered that if I access any page on the website before making a prediction call, it will never freeze, that is, if I open the website, make a prediction, then refresh the page I'm on or simply go to a different page, then make another prediction, it's good.
It works as long as I do something on the website before each prediction call.
If I start the webserver without accessing any page on the website and try to make a prediction from either the app or Postman, it will freeze. In order to make a successful prediction, I have to do something, anything, on the website, it doesn't seem to matter what page I access.

I used Postman to test it by sending the data and reading the response and it's the same thing, if I do something on the website between each prediction, it's fine, if I try to run predictions without interacting with the website first, it freezes.

I put in some statements to write to a static file on the server and found out that it fails when it tries to load the model:

`model = pickle.load(f)`

I tried moving the pickle.load function to apps.py and all that did was cause the site to fail to load because of the same pickle.load function.

I have tried putting the pickle.load inside a try/except and still get the same result.

The webserver shows httpd is good:

```
systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-05-11 08:36:26 PDT; 4min 57s ago
    Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 11960 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 117820 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 5; Idle/Busy workers 99/1;Requests/sec: 0.0173; Bytes served/sec:  74 B/sec"
    Tasks: 297 (limit: 23656)
   Memory: 90.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
        ├─117820 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        ├─117822 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        ├─117823 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        ├─117826 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        ├─117827 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        ├─117828 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
        └─118100 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

May 11 08:36:25 <mysite> systemd[1]: httpd.service: Succeeded.
May 11 08:36:25 <mysite> systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
May 11 08:36:25 <mysite> systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 11 08:36:26 <mysite> httpd[117820]: [Thu May 11 08:36:26.041188 2023] [so:warn] [pid 117820:tid 140091425315136] AH01574: module w>
May 11 08:36:26 <mysite> systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
May 11 08:36:26 <mysite> httpd[117820]: Server configured, listening on: port <port>, port <port>
```

Another interesting detail is that sometimes, for reasons unknown, it will spontaneously work.
Two days ago, after I had tried modifying the data I was sending to the function, (I substituted values[1],[2],[3],[7] to be 0 instead of actual measurements since they are not needed for this prediction), it worked perfectly for over an hour. The next day, when I tried to run it, with no code changes, no server changes, no app changes, it was back to freezing again. At the time it just started working, the only changes I was making were to the classify function in views.py. After it was working, I made several changes to the app and it continued to work with no problems until I stopped for the day.

I have tried omitting all of the data not specifically used for the prediction and get the same result. The problem seems to be specifically in loading the model.

Also, after the site freezes, If I wait ~5 minutes, it unfreezes, that is, I can access the website. If I try to make another prediction without doing something on the website, it still freezes. No matter what I try, I can only get a successful prediction if I do something on the site first.

I checked /var/log/httpd/error_log while the site was frozen and I tried accessing my main page and get the error:

```
[Thu May 11 15:30:14.070376 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 142897:tid 140541178107648] [client <ipaddress>:51310] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process '<Django Project>':<server path>/wsgi.py, referer: https://<mysite>/
```

I have tried replacing pickle with joblib and get the same result.

I have tried changing the name of the model in case there was some interference with the name "model" somewhere else and get the same result.

I tried using a different ML model, AdaBoost instead of Random Forest, same result.

I moved the view to a class instead of a function, same result.

As a workaround, I have made a python file in my directory that runs my prediction for me and I just use os.system to call it from my website eliminating the need to load the model in Django. This is working but I would really like to figure out what is causing this error so I can do it properly.